# filter data in apache velocity for loop

Tags: apache, xml-parsing, velocity

I am using Apache velocity to parse an xml file, let's say I have the following case:

My XML contains an `<animals>` root node which contains a `<dogs>` node with 3 children that are singular `<dog>`, each of them have a `<name>` node containing a value.

```
<animals>
    <dogs>
        <dog>
            <name>REX</name>
        </dog> 
        <dog>
            <name>FELIX</name>
        </dog> 
        <dog>
            <name>REX</name>
        </dog> 
    </dogs>
</animals>
```

In my velocity template, I have a `foreach` loop fetching all the `<dog>` nodes, something like this:

```
#foreach( $dog in $animals.dogs.children() )
    $dog.name.getText() 
#end
```

so, this basic example works, but what if I have to filter out of the foreach the dog that dosen't have FELIX as a name ? Looping only over dogs that have the name REX for example, I have tried using IF statements , but it dosen't work with getText(), is there a way of doing that directly in the foreach loop ?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the if statement instead of

```
$dog.name.getText()
```

use

```
$dog.name.text
```

---

#### Example

```
#foreach( $dog in $animals.dogs.children() )
    #if ($dog.name.text != 'whatever')
       ## do something
    #end
#end
```

---

## 4.3 Properties

> Velocity allows you to access properties through a short-hand notation. The objects to look up the properties must be
>   available through a Velocity variable and the notation consists of a leading variable followed by the dot (".")
>   character and another VTL Identifier.

```
$customer.address
$purchase.total
$cart.customerDiscount
```

## Example 4.2 Valid property names

> A property name can represent the following elements depending on the object used for look-up:

- If the object has a method get where the property name is not modified, this method is invoked
- else if the object is a Java bean (has methods conforming to the Sun Java Bean specification for accessing bean properties), the bean getter is executed to access the value
- finally if the object used to look up the property has a get(String) method, invoke this method.

Take the first example, $customer.address. It can have multiple meanings:1

- when the object has a method getaddress(), invoke this method
- when the object is a Java bean with a property address, invoke its getter, getAddress()
- when the object has a method get(String), invoke this method, passing address as parameter.
- when the object has a method isAddress(), invoke this method.

> Note When a property name refers to a getter method, $obj.property and $obj.Property will both
>   invoke the same method (either getproperty() or getProperty()). However, if the object
>   represented by $obj has a get(String) method, $obj.property and $obj.Property will
>   pass different values to this get(String) method. This can lead to hard-to-find problems. It's a
>   good practice to standardize the capitalization of property names in your application.
>   If you wonder about setting property values, please look up the #set() directive chapter. The setting of properties
>   is discussed there

https://people.apache.org/~henning/velocity/pdf/VelocityUsersGuide.pdf

**Just for your information the same shorthand is used in JSTL / EL**

Comment: thanks for the answer, it works, but I am not sure I understand why. Why isn't the getText() method resolved when used in an if statement ?

Comment: So you understand that JSTL uses a "convention over configuration" shorthand for accessor methods whereby a private String text variable with an accessory method public String getText() can be called in JSTL by simply typing the property name with dot notation?  Correct?  Well to take it a step further the convention over configuration specification is based off Oracle's JavaBean specification.  In other words if you have a class that follows the JavaBean naming convention you can use the shorthand notation.  However the specification is... well.. specific.  And because it follows this

Comment: shorthand notation there are a lot of particular cases where things don't act as you would expect. For example if you have a private boolean legal variable and a public boolean getLegal() method you cannot use shorthand because by JavaBean specification you need to prefix primitive booleans with is not get.  If you have a public Boolean isLegal() I believe thats wrong toobecause you are using the wrapper class not the primitive.  So while I cannot explicitly answer your question about your particular case - I can say that if you read the JavaBean spec and look over your source you will find it